# How can I get the Hadoop command-line scripts working on Win32?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, hadoop

I'm trying to build a Hadoop development environment on my Windows XP 32bit environment.

When I try to run one of the utilities I get an error message (see screenshot below). I'm pretty sure that the reason why it cannot find the right directory must be an incorrectly specified path - somewhere in the config file. (relevant portion shown below as well).

What is the correct way to specify the location of the JDK & Jars on a Win32 platform?

[image: Command line error]

[image: Configuration file]

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose path with quotes (double or single). It's seen on error that path is truncated by the space in Program_Files